# Extract text between pattern using REGEX

Tags: python, regex

I need help with regex in python.

I've got a large html file[around 400 lines] with the following pattern

```
text here(div,span,img tags)

<!-- 3GP||Link|| --> 

text here(div,span,img tags)
```

So, now i am searching for a regex expression which can extract me this-:

```
Link
```

The given pattern is unique in the html file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> d = """
... Some text here(div,span,img tags)
...
... <!-- 3GP||**Some link**|| -->
...
... Some text here(div,span,img tags)
... """
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\<!-- 3GP\|\|([^|]+)\|\| --\>',d)
['**Some link**']
```

- `r''` is a raw literal, it stops interpretation of standard string escapes
- `\<!-- 3GP\|\|` is a regexp escaped match for `<!-- 3GP||`
- `([^|]+)` will match everything upto a `|` and groups it for convenience
- `\|\| --\>` is a regexp escaped match for `|| -->`
- `re.findall` returns all non-overlapping matches of re pattern within a string, if there's a group expression in the re pattern, it returns that.

Comment: Thanks.It worked. If you don't mind can you please explain to me what you did there.

Comment: I think strictly speaking the `<` and `>` don't need escaping here, but it doesn't do any harm, they are metacharacters in other pattern implementations.

Comment: Thanks. A very nice explanation.Can you suggest me any good tutorial for learning regex.The problem is there are too many tutorials available.

Comment: Sadly no. I'd recommend reading the python docs for the re module, experimenting and asking questions when you get stuck. Decent syntax highlighter might help too

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.match(r"<!-- 3GP\|\|(.+?)\|\| -->", "<!-- 3GP||Link|| -->").group(1)
```

yields `"Link"`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to parse something else, you can also combine the regular expression with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(<your html here>)
link_regex = re.compile('\s+3GP\|\|(.*)\|\|\s+')
comment = soup.find(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)
                    and link_regex.match(text))
link = link_regex.match(comment).group(1)
print link
```

Note that in this case the regular expresion only needs to match the comment contents because BeautifulSoup already takes care of extracting the text from the comments.

Comment: My html is too malformed, thats why am not using beautiful soup.

Comment: I see, then I agree on that the best option is to use regular expressions to [sanitize your data](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Sanitizing%20Bad%20Data%20with%20Regexps).

Comment: Yes, thats what am going to do